# sed command not removing lines

Tags: linux, bash, sed, debian

I have the following shell script that will not delete lines in the intended file. Essentially I have a document with rows of data I would like to delete. In another file I have a list of GUIDs, and if the GUID matches I want to remove it from the source file.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read testing
do
echo $testing
sed -i "/$testing/d" /home/bbelden/ndp.CSV
done < t2.txt
```

When I run this lines do not get removed from the ndp.CSV file, and if I do a ps aux while it is running I see the following command:

```
root      17266  107  0.0  14880  1020 pts/1    R+   17:23   0:02 sed -i /58db9697-a5d5-98ab-200e-66d0c0767147?/d /home/bbelden/ndp.CSV
```

Not really sure what is going on here. I am running Debian 9.

Thanks

Comment: For some reason it seems to be adding that trailing question mark in the sed statement as seen in the ps aux statement. Not sure why it is doing that.

Comment: Check your `t2.txt` for carriage returns

Comment: So strange. I've used your same script and I got everything ok. Try to see the "real" content of your files using `cat -A <filenames>`, bot for ndp.CSV and t2.txt
Maybe you have strange characters in some of those files (I bet for t2.txt file)

Comment: Did you consider `grep -vf t2.txt /home/bbelden/ndp.CSV`?

Answer (score 2):

I had carriage returns at the end of each line since they were originally created in Windows. I was able to remove them, and now it is working as expected. Thank you!